# Unable to pass the array value in the Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Below is the code that I am using with Jquery to pass a value when a hyperlink is selected on sharepoint disp form.

```
for(var i=0;i<retval.length;i++)
{
 strHTML = strHTML +  "<a href='url.aspx?ID= '+retval[i]+' &Source= url'>" + retval[i] + "</a>";
 strHTML = strHTML + " ";
 }

  strHTML = strHTML + "</div>";


   $("textarea[Title='Test']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").contents().find("body").html(strHTML);
```

Its unable to read the value in retval[i], its breaking right at ID. Is the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the variable to evaluate, it needs to be **outside** of the quotes (as you did with the actual hyperlink's text):

```
strHTML = strHTML + "<a href='url.aspx?ID=" + retval[i] + "&source=url ...";
```

However, I would look at using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before placing it within a URL:

```
strHTML = strHTML + "<a href='url.aspx?ID=" + encodeURIComponent(retval[i]) + "&source=url ...";
```

*Also, try to avoid including spaces in the URL (make sure the variable, equal sign (`=`) and value are close together). Also, given the `href` attribute's value is surrounded by single quotes (`'`) you want to **avoid** using them in the middle of the URL (e.g. don't surround the ID's value within the URL with `'`).*

```
var id = 'foo';

var bad  = "<a href='target.aspx?ID='"+id+"''>Invalid</a>";
//  bad = <a href="target.aspx?ID='foo''>Invalid</a>
// note that the single quotes now interfere

var good = "<a href='target.aspx?ID="+id+"'>Valid</a>";
//  good = "<a href='target.aspx?ID=foo'>Valid</a>";    
// note now that the quotes align and the value is acceptable
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more readable:

```
var atag = "url.aspx?ID="+encodeURIComponenet(retval[i])+"&Source=url";
strHTML = strHTML +  "<a href='"+atag+"'>" + retval[i] + "</a> ";
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the double quotes surrounding the entire string:

```
"<a href='url.aspx?ID= '+retval[i]+' &Source= url'>"
```

Its reading the +reval[i]+ as part of the string, what you want to do differentiate between string and command. You will need to use the double quote to end the string and add your command. You will need to change the above to:

```
"<a href='url.aspx?ID=" + retval[i] + "&Source=url'>"
```